# Gini and Lift With Transformed Variable

Tags: data-transformation, gini

With regards to Gini Index/Net Lift, If I build a model where the target value is transformed by something - say natural log for example - will the Gini and Lift calculated on the transformed variable be the same on the actual variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uni-variate Gini and Lift values will be different. This is because the probabilities you estimate will change based on the transformation you choose.

Consider a logistic regression model without an intercept term

$$\log(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}) = \beta x_i.$$

If you transform $x_i$ (assuming that $x_i > 0\hspace{0.1cm} \forall i$) using $\log(\cdot)$, then the logistic regression model would become

$$\log(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}) = \beta' \log(x_i)$$

and the estimated probabilities $\pi_i$ would change, which means your Gini/ROC curve will change, and so will your Gini.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Maybe this is obvious, but I want to ask to be sure, if I'm predicting y and I model using sqrt(y), and say I get a better Gini/ROC on the sqrt(y) is this still valid in predicting y? I feel like the answer is yes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If $Y$ is binary, then it wouldn't make sense to transform it.

Comment: What if it wasn’t binary?

Comment: ROC curves are only meant to be used on binary classifiers (i.e. $Y = \{0, 1\}$).

Comment: Again, I appreciate the explanation. However, I never specified binary only. I say in the title Gini coefficient which isn’t limited to binary.

Comment: May I ask what your application is?